# Install Hector Slam on Raspberry Pi running Kinetic / Jessie

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I feel I am so near to where I want to be with my Robot, people on here have been brilliant!!

I have a Robot (Pi) running Lidar (Neato) and I want to get Hector Mapping working with it.  The Problem is I am running ROS Kinetic and Jessie on the PI?  I seen how I could do it if I was running Ubuntu Mate on the Pi.

Anyone got any ideas?  I thought the below would work

rosinstall_generator ros_hector_slam --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-custom_ros.rosinstall

I have also tried going to the catkin /src
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git
However it does not seem to build

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "nav_msgs" with any
of the following names:

```
nav_msgsConfig.cmake
nav_msgs-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251395/install-hector-slam-on-raspberry-pi-running-kinetic-/-jessie/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered that you can just compile from source (github) and that works.  However I actually reverted to Indigo on my Pi as it seems a lot more mature (and just works)

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0